# Can't use laravel auth login/register

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-5.1

I try to make a login/register simple app with laravel...
I currently use 5.2 version of laravel.

At route I write:

```
Route::controllers([
     'auth'=>'Auth\AuthController',
     'password'=>'Auth\PasswordController', ]);
```

SO now when I try to register user at localhost:8888/auth/register - I fill fields but when I click register then I get error message:

> FatalErrorException in User.php line 8: Class
>   'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User' not found

[image]

So how I can use auth at laravel 5.2? How I can downgrade laravel from 5.2 to 5.1 version?
What you suggest? How I can solve my problem?

Comment: What version of 5.2 are you using? The latest stable version is 5.1.26.

Comment: What does your composer.json look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message no such class exists and therefore its throwing an exception. Remove line 8 from your User model. I suspect the foundation class should be

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
```

but without seeing the code I'm guessing. I'd suggest posting your controller, route and view code for us to help you. Registration and auth are fairly straightforward so post the code and let's see how we can help.